# Did I make a mistake when finding the intervals this function is continuous on?

Tags: continuity, piecewise-continuity

I was given a function $f$ given by$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x^2 - a^2}{x - a \;}&\text{if} \; x \neq a, \\
2a & \text{if} \; x=a,
\end{cases}$$
and told to find the intervals over which $f$ is continuous, in terms of $a$. I just figured it is continous everywhere except $a$, so the intervals would be $(-\infty, a)$ and $(a, \infty)$. However, my textbook gives the answer, without working, as $(-\infty, -a)$ and $(-a, \infty)$. I'm like $99\%$ sure this is a mistake by the textbook author, not me, but continuity and the like is not my strong side, so I just want to make sure I didn't make a mistake here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, and I am giving the answer in terms of $a$.

Comment: You are right, the function is continuos everywhere except at $x = a$ ... Yet another textbook error :)

Comment: Why is this not continuous at $a$?

Comment: @MarkBennet it is not continous because $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$ is undefined.

Comment: @caverac, thanks :) I can't accept your answer since you only posted a comment.

Comment: OP you are right it is continuous everywhere.

Comment: The limit does not depend on the value at $x=a$ - the limit is defined. The function is continuous if the limit is equal to the defined value. You will have problems differentiating $f(x)=x^2$ if you think that the limit is not defined.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the function **is** in fact continous everywhere. Check the limit for $x\rightarrow a$ of $f(x)$

Comment: Made a mistake. The function is continuous everywhere  sorry about that

Comment: @caverac no worries. I make the same mistake you did with $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is $$\frac{x^2-a^2}{x-a}=x+a$$ if $x\neq$ $a$ and 
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^2-a^2}{x-a}=2a$$ thus our function is continous for all real $x$

Comment: I think this is the right answer. I just made a mistake earlier when evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to a}f(x)$, but now I agree it is contionus for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think the given solution is wrong(in your textbook)

Comment: Yeah I figured. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To the proposer:  $f(x)=x+a$ for all $x$. Clearly this is continuous for all $x.$